# how to reference the object inside a UIControl in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, binding

So at first I create a uicontrol A ,In **MainWindow.xaml.cs**, I can click a button to create a new A and then I use A.DataContext = new Book(....). Also, in the Uicontrol, i can click a button to call the following method

```
private void OnShowBook(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Book theBook = this.DataContext as Book;
    if (theBook != null)
        MessageBox.Show(theBook.Title, theBook.Isbn);
}
```

This works because I created a new Book using A.DataContent =... before.

Now I changed a little bit. i did not create an instance using A.DataContent = new Book(...). Instead I created another `BookFactory.cs` to hold the data and in the Uicontrol i used

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="theBook" ObjectType="local:BookFactory" MethodName="GetTheBook" />
<Grid x:Name="grid1" DataContext="{StaticResource theBook}">
```

to use it.  Every thing works except the **button-->OnshowBook**. My question is in this case how to access the Book object inside the Uicontrol XAML file ?

**Update new question**

I've tried to use

```
private void OnShowBook(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    Book thebook = ((this.FindResource("theBook") as ObjectDataProvider).Data as Book);
    if (thebook != null)
        MessageBox.Show(thebook.Title, thebook.Isbn);
}
```

The codes compiles ok but throws error at runtime. it can not find key **theBook** which i indeed declared.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. i found out something . I need to use `FindResource` to access  the object inside xmal.